# Как проверить число на четность?

Tags: javascript

Пишу функцию, которая принимает целое число и возвращает строку - четное или не четное число.

```
function even_or_odd(number) {
  return number mod 2 ? "Odd" : "Even"
}
```

никак не пойму что неправильно?

Comment: `['Even', 'Odd'](number % 2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конструкции `mod` в JS нет. Зато есть `%`:

```js
const even = n => !(n % 2);

console.info(even(5));
console.info(even(4));
```

Answer (score 8):

Вы на каком языке пишите ? Я вижу что тут есть доля паскаля `mod`.
Так вот, что бы на `js` узнать является ли число четным, то нужно делать так

```js
function even_or_odd(number) {
      return number % 2 === 0 ? "Odd" : "Even"
}

console.log(even_or_odd(3));
console.log(even_or_odd(2));
```

Comment: пишу на javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
var isEven=n=>(n&1)?"odd":"even";
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
function IsOdd(numb){
     var number = numb;
     if(Math.floor(number / 2) == number / 2) {
         //Чётное
         return false;
     }else{
         //Нечётное
         return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Что-что?........

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `['odd', 'even'][number & 1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
function evenOrOdd(number) {
  a = 'Even'
  b = 'Odd'
  if (number % 2 === 0 ) {
    return a } else {
      return b
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, уточните прямо в тексте ответа (нажав [edit]), что нового добавляет ваш ответ к уже существующим ответам.

Comment: Ужасный код: ненужные переменные, нестандартное форматирование, устаревший синтаксис. Прямо инструкция "как не надо".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а где устаревший синтаксис?

Comment: @Grundy, `function` пора заменить на стрелки. Они выглядят лучше, и семантика у них менее косячная.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну не, стрелки это стрелки, function Это function, стрелки не всегда удобны. Ну, и то, что тебе не нравится function - не делает их устаревшими :)

Comment: @Grundy, `function` создаёт `arguments` (производительность), `function` всплывает на верх (проблемы с семантикой), `function` волшебно определяет `this`, `function` разрешает использование `new` (устаревший ООП механизм). Всего этого достаточно чтобы с ним не водится. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-difference-between-arrow-functions-and-normal-functions/

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, _function создаёт arguments (производительность)_ - без конкретных замеров (желательно в разных браузерах) не очень убедительно звучит. Определение this - строго специфицировано и никакого волшебства. Про `new` не понял, почему `new` - это устаревший `ООП` механизм 

Comment: @Grundy, `new Function` - прототипное наследование. Зачем если в JavaScript уже есть нормальные классы.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а ты же понимаешь, что под капотом у них все то же прототипное наследование?

Comment: @Grundy, понимаю. Плохо что любая функция `function` - конструктор, даже если в этом нет смысла.